# Excel sumifs multiple "<>" on one column

Tags: excel

I currently have the following formula.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(L$11),INDIRECT(D$6),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},$C$6,$C$7,$C$8,$C$9,$C$10,$C$11,$C$12,$C$13,$C$14,$C$15,$C$16),INDIRECT(L$8),">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(1),1),INDIRECT(L$8),"<"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(1)+3,1),INDIRECT(L$12),">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(1)+3,1)))
```

It is essentially trying to sum a range based on the criteria stated within my choose function, and then testing to see if they fall within a specific date range. Now, I also want to add a check on a new column, which is essentially a subtype for the data found within the column I use for the choose function.

I want to exclude specific strings found within that column. So I figured that "<>" would be my best option. However, I am having an issue with trying to use multiple "<>" on the same column. I have tried using another choose function, but that is returning the incorrect answer.

I have stared at this code for many hours. My brain is just about finished. Am I missing something?

I know I am using volatile functions, but this is for testing purposes.

EDIT_
I have updated a simple version of my code into a mini workbook, essentially I want to exclude heavy and encumbered from my total calculation. but include whatever other types are in my subtype column.

```
Random Dollar Values    Start Date  End Date    Sub-Types   Super Type
$474,036.00 01/01/16    4/04/2016   encumbered  Hat
$474,036.00 01/01/16    5/04/2016   encumbered  backpack
$474,036.00 01/01/16    6/04/2016   encumbered  pants
$474,036.00 01/01/16    7/04/2016   encumbered  shoes
$474,036.00 01/01/16    8/04/2016   encumbered  socks
$333,173.00 01/01/16    9/04/2016   encumbered  shorts
$474,036.00 01/01/16    10/04/2016  encumbered  jumper
$296,042.00 01/01/16    11/04/2016      collar
$261,503.00 01/01/16    12/04/2016  encumbered  ball
$451,112.00 01/01/16    13/04/2016      bag
```

Total = =SUM(SUMIFS(Data!A:A,Data!E:E,CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12),Data!B:B,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(1),1),Data!B:B,"<"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(1)+3,1),Data!C:C,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(1)+3,1)))

Each cell reference is just a quick link to their string name.

I basically want to exlude the two sub types I mentioned above.

I tried doing , D:D, "<>"&"Heavy", D:D"<>"&Encumbered") but that didn't work. nor did using a second choose function.

Comment: This question needs sample data together with expected results.

Comment: I have supplied sample data

Comment: Does anyone have any insight into how I could get this to work?